# How do i make my hair particles follow the emmiter?

Tags: particles, hair, parent

Beginner here. I am making a stylised dandelion and have used a hair emitter and a turbulence forcefield to give it some soft movement at the puff. I want to also have some turbulence on the whole plant including the stalk, so it waves around both at the "root" of  plant and the individual puffs wave around as well. I thought i would parent all my objects (Stalk, Emmiter, Puff object and turbulence FF) to an empty so i'd be able to treat it as one object? But when i rotate the empty to test it, the hair particles detach from the emitter and stay in place.

Is this even the right way to achieve this? How can i have a second turbulence forcefield affect the whole thing, while keeping the turbulence i have at the puff at the top?

Thanks for any help!

[image: Dandelion with Turbulence force field at the top round the puff][image: rotate the parent empty but its detached from the emmiter][image: object hierarchy in scene mode]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the answer of [this question.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162913/the-particles-doesnt-move-with-emitter)

I used the workaround described by moving the emitter and then cancelling, then it updated the position.